# How to alter or log a variable in a plugin?

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, plugin, debugging

**Background**

I've built a custom shipping method.  It follows almost an identical pattern to the magento shipping method classes.  It works as expected.  Then I added a plugin to check if a coupon code was entered the field would appear.  This works as well.

**The Issue**

I want to attach the coupon name to the shipping method title.  So instead of saying "Event Pickup FREE" it says "EVENT LOCATION - Event Pickup - FREE".  Making an `afterCollectRates` function I would assume I would need to alter the `$result` variable.

I can't seem to figure out how to:

1. Properly alter $result to override the data.
2. Debug or log $result to see the structure of the object.  In hopes to alter it.

**Shipping Method Function**

```
  public function collectRates(RateRequest $request)
  {
    if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active')) {
        return false;
    }

    /** @var \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result $result */
    $result = $this->_rateResultFactory->create();

    /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Method $method */
    $method = $this->_rateMethodFactory->create();

    $method->setCarrier($this->_code);
    $method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));

    $method->setMethod($this->_code);
    $method->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));  //<--This is what the plugin should change

    $method->setPrice('0.00');
    $method->setCost('0.00');

    $result->append($method);

    return $result;
  }
```

**Plugin for Shipping Method**

```
public function afterCollectRates(\Base\Model\Carrier\EventPickup $subject, $result)
{

    if (!$this->checkCouponCode()) {
            return false;
    }

    $couponCode = $this->_coupon->getCouponCode()


    $this->_logger->debug($couponCode); //<--This works and shows up on log

    return $result;
}
```

I've attempted to use the logger, debug, var_dump, echo, print_r, var_export and any other combinations.  All seem to be no use.  The result is usually the same, the magento loader spins forever 
and nothing regarding $result comes to the log.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't log objects. But you can log data of it. For debug logging I usually use Zend logger with custom writer:

```
        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/test.log');
    $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
    $logger->addWriter($writer);
    $logger->info($result->getAllRates()[0]->getData());
```

And as you can already guess - you can change your method like this: `$result->getAllRates()[0]->setData('data_name', 'new_data_value')`

Hope it will help.

Comment: This looks promising - I'll take a look and report back.  thanks!

Comment: @SpencerRohan nice to hear. Enjoy coding!